QGIS 3.28.9 crash when using Random Points in Polygon
I'm trying to create points in a raster layer of livestock chickens data. After creating an output raster with the values of interest, I used the Polygonize tool to vectorize the output raster. At this point, I need to create points inside the polygons to symbolize these areas.
I used the Processing Toolbox > Vector Creation > Random Points in Polygons with the parameters shown in the image below:

However, after running this process, QGIS crashes. Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Can you please show the log from the QGIS crash?

There is no log window after crash... Where can I find the logs when I reopen QGIS?

Polygons created with the Polygonize tool may have topology errors. Try to validate the layer first.
